# How to load tensorflow lite model on Xamarin Android app

Tags: tensorflow, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tensorflow-lite

I want to load a `.tflite` model on my Xamarin Android app.

I've tried loading it with TensorFlow `Interpreter`

```
var file = new Java.IO.File("C:\\Users\\Jaime\\source\\repos\\IdentificadorImagenesSolution\\IdentificadorImagenes\\IdentificadorImagenes.Android\\Assets\\detect.tflite");
var model = new Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Interpreter(file);
```

and I get this `Exception`

`The model is not a valid Flatbuffer file`

But i cant find `FlatBuffer` class inside the bindings of tflite for Xamarin, would be helpful if someone knows how could i load my model.

Comment: are you sure that file is not null?  You are passing it a desktop file path, which Android cannot open

Comment: you are probably right, gonna keep looking

Comment: include it in your project and load from there, or load it from a url

Comment: i have the file in my assets folder but still giving me the same issue

Comment: Make sure you have given the right file access permissions and that the "Build action" is correct. It should work when loaded in your assets. What tutorial/docs are you trying to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Got help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889099/xamarin-tf-lite-input-objects)

```
{
    var assets = Application.Context.Assets;
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.OpenFd("detect.tflite");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor);
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.Channel;
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.StartOffset;
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.DeclaredLength;
    var asd = fileChannel.Map(FileChannel.MapMode.ReadOnly, startOffset, declaredLength);
    var model = new Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Interpreter(asd);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

make sure you go to `Project->Project Properties-> Android Options->Leave resource extensions with out compress` and add `.tflite` to it.