# Using Xamarin - Running TensorFlow Lite examples in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

It is hard to find resources online regarding implementing TensorFlow Lite with Xamarin. I am trying to reproduce the same thing from the question from this [stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889099/xamarin-tf-lite-input-objects?newreg=be8292ae9bd9471993a4884ce9bafd04) as well as the linked stack overflow pages. I am very new to Xamarin and TensorFlow, so need help here. What I did is simply copy paste to `MainActivity.cs` of a new solution created in Visual Studio. With NuGet package `Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite`.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Java.IO;
using Java.Nio;
using Java.Nio.Channels;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
        fab.Click += FabOnClick;
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;
        if (id == Resource.Id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        View view = (View) sender;
        Snackbar.Make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LengthLong)
            .SetAction("Action", (Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener)null).Show();
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private MappedByteBuffer LoadModelFile()
    {
        var assets = Application.Context.Assets;
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.OpenFd("seed_model_no_qt.tflite");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor);
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.Channel;
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.StartOffset;
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.DeclaredLength;
        return fileChannel.Map(FileChannel.MapMode.ReadOnly, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    private string Classify(MediaFile mediaFile)
    {
        var assets = Application.Context.Assets;

        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(mediaFile.GetStream());
        var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bp, 1280, 1280, false).Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, false);

        var bufint = new int[1280 * 1280];
        resizedBitmap.GetPixels(bufint, 0, 1280, 0, 0, 1280, 1280);
        int pixels = 0;
        var input_buffer = new byte[4 * 1280 * 1280 * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1280; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 1280; k++)
            {
                int val = bufint[pixels++];
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * (1f / 255f)), 0, input_buffer, (i * 1280 + k) * 12, 4);
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * (1f / 255f)), 0, input_buffer, (i * 1280 + k) * 12 + 4, 4);
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((val & 0xFF) * (1f / 255f)), 0, input_buffer, (i * 1280 + k) * 12 + 8, 4);
            }
        }
        var bytebuffer = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.Wrap(input_buffer);
        var output = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.AllocateDirect(4 * 160 * 160);
        Interpreter.Run(bytebuffer, output);

        var buffer = new byte[4 * 160 * 160];

        Marshal.Copy(output.GetDirectBufferAddress(), buffer, 0, 4 * 160 * 160);

        float sum = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 160 * 160; i++)
        {
            sum += BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, i * 4);
        }

        return "Count : " + ((int)(sum / 255)).ToString();
    }
}
```

}

The particular problem I am facing is this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Interpreter.Run(Object, Object)` even though I am `using Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite;`

I am not sure where to start to solve this problem because I am very new to Xamarin.

Comment: The error msg is clear, you are not instancing a `Interpreter` object, i.e. `var myInterpreter = new Interpreter(someBuffer);` and then call that instance's `Run` method.

Comment: After I did what you mentioned, yes it has no errors now. Thanks @SushiHangover !

Comment: @SebastianKong Hi , if have solved , remember to share the solution in answer .

Comment: After some time working on it, it has no compile errors, but I haven't actually called that function. When the interpreter is called with my own model, some errors pop out. However, it is probably not related to this question. So need some time to research on it or else am not sure this is answered.

Comment: @SebastianKong What is your experience, understanding and recommendation of using TensorFlow for ML with Xamarin? What are limitations of Xamarin in Data AI and ML.